# How to create node service with feathersjs and redis 4?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, feathersjs

I'm new to node/express and trying to create a service that will use redis. So far only this key is in redis:

```
testkey: "Hello, Redis!"
```

I've set up this service (`src/services/redis/redis.class.ts`):

```
import { Id, NullableId, Params, ServiceMethods } from '@feathersjs/feathers'
import { Application } from '../../declarations'
import { createClient } from 'redis'
import { promisify } from 'util'

interface RedisData {
  key: string
  value: string
}

interface ServiceOptions {}

export class RedisService implements ServiceMethods<RedisData> {
  private client: any
  private getAsync: (key: string) => Promise<string>
  private setAsync: (key: string, value: string) => Promise<unknown>
  private delAsync: (key: string) => Promise<unknown>

  constructor(
    private options: ServiceOptions = {},
    private app: Application | null = null
  ) {
    this.client = createClient() // Configure this as needed
    console.log(this.client)
    this.getAsync = promisify(this.client.get).bind(this.client)
    this.setAsync = promisify(this.client.set).bind(this.client)
    this.delAsync = promisify(this.client.del).bind(this.client)
  }

  // FeathersJS service methods:

  async find(params?: Params): Promise<RedisData[] | RedisData> {
    throw new Error('Find method not implemented on Redis service')
  }

  async get(id: Id, params?: Params): Promise<RedisData> {
    if (id) {
      console.log('attempt getAsync...')
      const value = await this.getAsync('testkey') // won't run
      console.log(value)
      return { key: id.toString(), value }
    } else {
      throw new Error('id must be provided')
    }
  }

  async create(data: RedisData, params?: Params): Promise<RedisData> {
    await this.setAsync(data.key, data.value)
    return data
  }

  async update(
    id: NullableId,
    data: RedisData,
    params?: Params
  ): Promise<RedisData> {
    throw new Error('Update method not implemented on Redis service')
  }

  async patch(
    id: NullableId,
    data: RedisData,
    params?: Params
  ): Promise<RedisData> {
    throw new Error('Patch method not implemented on Redis service')
  }

  async remove(id: NullableId, params?: Params): Promise<RedisData> {
    if (id) {
      await this.delAsync(id.toString())
      return { key: id.toString(), value: '' }
    } else {
      throw new Error('id must be provided')
    }
  }
}
```

which won't run `this.getAsync('testkey')`, showing this error:

```
attempt getAsync...
Possibly Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  Promise {
<rejected> ClientClosedError: The client is closed
  at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/var/www/html/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:490:31)
  at Commander.commandsExecutor (/var/www/html/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:188:154)
  at Commander.BaseClass.<computed> [as get] (/var/www/html/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
  at node:internal/util:364:7
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Commander.<anonymous> (node:internal/util:350:12)
  at Object.get (/var/www/html/src/services/redis/redis.class.ts:39:32)
  at /var/www/html/node_modules/@feathersjs/feathers/lib/hooks/index.js:57:33
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at /var/www/html/node_modules/@feathersjs/feathers/lib/hooks/index.js:54:27
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
}  reason:  ClientClosedError: The client is closed
  at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/var/www/html/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:490:31)
  at Commander.commandsExecutor (/var/www/html/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:188:154)
  at Commander.BaseClass.<computed> [as get] (/var/www/html/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
  at node:internal/util:364:7
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Commander.<anonymous> (node:internal/util:350:12)
  at Object.get (/var/www/html/src/services/redis/redis.class.ts:39:32)
  at /var/www/html/node_modules/@feathersjs/feathers/lib/hooks/index.js:57:33
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at /var/www/html/node_modules/@feathersjs/feathers/lib/hooks/index.js:54:27
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  {"month":"2023-07"}
```

when I log `this.client` it returns:

```
Commander {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  commandOptions: [Function: commandOptions],
  select: [AsyncFunction: SELECT],
  subscribe: [Function: SUBSCRIBE],
  unsubscribe: [Function: UNSUBSCRIBE],
  pSubscribe: [Function: PSUBSCRIBE],
  pUnsubscribe: [Function: PUNSUBSCRIBE],
  sSubscribe: [Function: SSUBSCRIBE],
  sUnsubscribe: [Function: SUNSUBSCRIBE],
  quit: [Function: QUIT],
  multi: [Function: MULTI],
  bf: {},
  cms: {},
  cf: {},
  tDigest: {},
  topK: {},
  graph: {},
  json: {},
  ft: {},
  ts: {},
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Am I using `createClient()` wrong?

This file might also play a role (`src/services/redis/redis.service.ts`):

```
// Initializes the `users` service on path `/users`
import { ServiceAddons } from '@feathersjs/feathers'
import { Application } from '../../declarations'
import { RedisService } from './redis.class'
import hooks from './redis.hooks'

// Add this service to the service type index
declare module '../../declarations' {
  interface ServiceTypes {
    redis: any & ServiceAddons<any>
  }
}

export default function (app: Application): void {
  const options = {}

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/redis', new RedisService(options, app))

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks
  const service = app.service('redis')

  service.hooks(hooks)
}
```

also this: (`src/services/redis/redis.hooks.ts`):

```
import * as authentication from '@feathersjs/authentication'
import createDomainRobotInstance from '../../hooks/create-domain-robot-instance'
import getPermissions from '../../hooks/getPermissions'
import createConnectionLogID from '../../hooks/createConnectionLogID'

const { authenticate } = authentication.hooks

export default {
  before: {
    all: [authenticate('jwt'), getPermissions(), createConnectionLogID()],
    find: [createDomainRobotInstance()],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },
}
```

I'm calling the service from a `vue frontend` like so:

```
const client = inject('feathersClient')

const value = await client?.service('redis').get('testkey')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're working off of old examples for Node Redis 3. Node Redis 4 added Promises so you no longer need to use promisify. Just call the commands and await them:

```js
await this.set('testkey', 'foo')
const value = await this.client.get('testkey')
```

More details can be found in the [README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) for Node Redis.